# invoke-virtual vs invoke-direct in constructors

Tags: java, dalvik, smali

I'm working on performance monitoring system, which could inject its routines into existing assembly. For that, I'm trying to understand how dalvik code works.

Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish. Input class could look like this:

```
class MyClass{
    public MyClass(__params__){
        //initialization code
    }
}
```

I want to add code for the class to look like this:

```
class MyClass{
    public MyClass(__params__){
        this(_params__,0);
        //tracking and performance initialization code
    }

    public MyClass(__params__, int init){
        //old initialization code
    }
}
```

What was causing most bugs so far is the distinction between `invoke-direct` and `invoke-virtual` when calling one constructor from another.

When calling methods, this is straightforward (if method is private, it's called with `invoke-direct`, otherwise `invoke-virtual`). This doesn't seem to be the case for constructors.

What are the rules of calling `invoke-direct` vs`invoke-virtual` when invoking one constructor from another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke one constructor from another:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int x;

    public Foo()
    {
        this(1);
    }

    public Foo(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. you can only chain to one constructor, and it has to be the first statement in your constructor body.
2. If you want to chain inherited constructor, you can use `super` instead of `this`.
3. `invoke-direct` is used for `constructors` and `private methods`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I fixed the code in the question

Comment: I'm trying to invoke one constructor from another, and the code you mentioned probably will compile to Foo() using invoke-direct to call Foo(int)

Comment: @ArsenZahray : What is your requirement?

Comment: I need to know under which circumstances a constructor uses invoke-virtual to call another constructor, and under which invoke-direct

Comment: invoke-virtual is never used to call a constructor